# Cannot push after BFG Repo-Cleaner

Tags: git, gitlab, bfg-repo-cleaner

We have a self-hosted Gitlab instance.

I used BFG-Repo-Cleaner and everything went well, but when I try to push changes I get this:

remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to force push code to a protected branch on this project.

P.S. I'm owner of the project. 
Earlier I made fork of this project and I had no problems pushing changes there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you know what you are doing and you really want to force a push. GitLab disallows a forced push to the master branch by default. You can remove that protection. Click the cogwheel icon in your project and select `Protected branches`. Then click the `Unprotect` button for the master branch. The forced push will work then.