# cant push to remote repo in gitlab eventhough I'm the owner

Tags: permissions, gitlab, git-push

I'm an owner of a GitLab repository, but when I try to push from a local machine, using an access token that I generated on GitLab's page, it fails.

> Writing objects: 100% (980/980), 8.49 MiB | 3.22 MiB/s, done.
> Total 980 (delta 537), reused 0 (delta 0)
> remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (537/537), done.
> remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to force push code to a protected branch on this project.
> To https://myurl.git
> ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246503/fix-gitlab-error-you-are-not-allowed-to-push-code-to-protected-branches-on-thi) SO post, it says that an 'owner'(and 'maintainer') can push

how can I solve this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force push to Gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54100604/how-to-force-push-to-gitlab)

Answer (score 7):

The branch you try to force push to is protected. This is a setting, you can change in your project in Settings > Repository > protected branches.

This feature gives you as a maintainer and owner additional flexibility in controlling branch access and although you are allowed to push. you are not allowed to force push, as soon as a branch is protected.

This means, you need to deactivate branch protection for the branch you try to push too.

From the [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html#overview):

> By default, a protected branch does these things:
>
> - It prevents its creation, if not already created, from everybody except users with Maintainer permission.
> - It prevents pushes from everybody except users with Allowed permission.
> - It prevents anyone from force pushing to the branch.
> - It prevents anyone from deleting the branch.

[image]